# Trigger event from Html Button in webview Xamarin iOS

Tags: webview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am struggling to trigger an event of an html `Link Button` in my `WebView`. I can't find a way around. What I'm doing is as:

```
public void ViewDidLoad(bool animation)
{
    var yourWebView = new UIWebView(new CGRect("YourViewFrame"));
    string htmlString = "<html>Hey!  try this, I'm sure It will work, Now,  <a href='Home.html'>ClickMe</a> Go for it...</html>";
    yourWebView.LoadHtmlString(htmlString, null);
}
```

I tried Javascript and webhybrid but that doesn't suffice my requirement. How can i do this to get Clicl Me Hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to to grab an event from Webview then you must use `UIWebViewDelegate` there you will identify fired event. Take a look at the following code snippet.

```
public void ViewDidLoad(bool animation)
{
    var yourWebView = new UIWebView(new CGRect("YourViewFrame"));
    yourWebView.Delegate =new YourWebViewDelegate(this);
    string htmlString = "<html>Hey!  try this, I'm sure It will work, Now,  <a href='Home.html'>ClickMe</a> Go for it...</html>";
    yourWebView.LoadHtmlString(htmlString, null);
}
```

Create delegate class that will handle your click action. //Magic

```
public class YourWebViewDelegate : UIWebViewDelegate
{
    UIViewController CurrentInstance;

    public YourWebViewDelegate(UIViewController _currentInstance)
    {
        CurrentInstance = _currentInstance;
    }

    public override bool ShouldStartLoad(UIWebView webView, NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType)
    {
        if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked)
        {
            CurrentInstance.NavigationController.PushViewController(new YourViewControllerToNavigate(), true);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Cheers!!